# Font size in css

Tags: html, css, font-size

I just want to make my text bigger. I tried em, px,% and pt, but it's still one size. What's wrong? 
UPD:
Thanks everybody, but I don't need your help anymore. I did it. Also I can't delete this question.

```
body {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #717171;
    }

a {
    color: #3298BA;
}

a:hover {
    color: #D62C88;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: This code isn't the problem. My guess is the font-size gets overridden by a more specific selector. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: Use the developer tools to inspect your styles and where they come from. It looks like your font-size just gets overriden.

Comment: What do you mean "overriden"? Do you mean "<small>" tags or something?

Comment: @user26393777 Overridden usually refers to a bit of CSS with !important at the end.  Do a quick search to see if you have !important somewhere  in your CSS.

Comment: If you have `<p>Blaa</p>` and a `font-size` definition set on `body` as well as `p`, the `p` definition will take effect. Thats meant by overridden.

Comment: Nope. Look at the topic. This is my only css code.

Comment: Then your css is not included properly. This css works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/qsY4K/1/

Comment: Can you paste your html content as well please ?

Comment: “I don't need your help anymore” is not constructive. This is not a helpdesk. But since there is no well-defined question and apparently no willingness to improve the question, it is best closed.

Answer (score -1):

Your CSS is correct. It is working just fine. Here is your code. Which one I tested.
http://jsbin.com/ayihet/1

Answer (score -2):

Change to:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em !important;
    color: #717171;
}
```

It's not the best solution, but given what we're presented with it's the only way I can think of solving the issue.

Comment: Using `!important` just tends to hide the real problem, leaving it lurking.

Comment: The fact that this is down voted is stupid.  We were given very little information about his specific problem.  SO is about solving specific problems, not necessarily the best coding practices.

Comment: No real problem was presented, so there was no reason to recommend the `!important` snake oil.

Comment: Real problem or not, this answer solved his specific issue.  Stack Overflow is not a forum for general questions and answers, it deals with specific questions and answers to solve said questions.

Comment: It cannot have solved any issue if the statement “This is my only css code” in a comment was true. For all we can know, accepting the answer was a mistake.